# Checking that a value from a table does not exists in another table sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a Table Valued Parameter that contains guids as a field and I want to enter it's values into another table where the guid does not exist

Which is the best way to do this.

The check I am doing at the moment doesnt seem right.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT F.FieldKey FROM @Fields F INNER JOIN DomainObjectFields DOF ON F.FieldKey = DOF.UniqueKey)

--@Fields is the tvp and DomainObjectFields is the regular table I want to add values to
```

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'd use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` myself.

```
INSERT INTO DomainObjectFields (UniqueKey)
SELECT F.FieldKey 
FROM @Fields F 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DomainObjectFields DOF 
    ON DOF.FieldKey = F.UniqueKey
WHERE DOF.UniqueKey IS NULL
```